# Setup vscode MyPy for project with both Python2 and Python3

Tags: visual-studio-code, mypy, vscode-python

I have a vscode linux based project that is mainly **Python2.7**.  The project started well before Python3 had momentum.

In vscode settings I have to following to specify the code is for python2.

```json
"python.linting.mypyArgs": [ "--py2" ],
```

Now, I have to add in some new code/modules/packages that are written in **Python3**.

**Can I configure vscode mypy to use Python3 linting for some files/directories and Python2 linting for other files/directories ?  If so, how?**